# CSS: как сделать полное обтекание одного блока остальными

Tags: css

**Чтобы красные блоки, полностью окружали синий, и не было пустых мест**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .a {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      display: inline-flex;
    }
    
    .b {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: blue;
      display: inline-flex;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    for (var i = 1; i < 40; i++) {
      switch (i) {
        case 20:
          document.writeln('<div class="b"></div>');
          break;
        default:
          document.writeln('<div class="a"></div>');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Пример кода покажите.

Comment: Тут несколько способов решения вашего вопроса, добавьте свой код (или свои попытки написания кода), для того чтоб вам помогли

Comment: Добавил код....

Answer (score 4):

Вариант на гридах:

```css
.main-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.block-red,
.block-blue {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.block-red {
  background: red;
}

.block-blue {
  background: blue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 5;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-container">
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-blue"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
  <div class="block-red"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Как в варианте на гридах растянуть на всю ширину экрана?

Comment: Он сейчас уже сделан на всю ширину. При этом каждый красный блок - 1\5 экрана.

Comment: В хроме занимает процентов 20, примерно: https://www.screencast.com/t/e4GOiQNS4nli

Comment: Можно, чтобы блоки были фиксированной ширины и высоты. 100*100px и 300*300px, например

Comment: Проверьте масштабирование в браузере, поставьте по умолчанию.

Comment: Фиксированные размеры блоков можно, но тогда и ширину контейнера придётся зафиксировать.

Comment: Вот вариант с фиксированными размерами блоков 
 https://codepen.io/Yurkin/pen/MZLWGy